# How to include a webpack module to file protocol

Tags: webview, webpack, ecmascript-6, electron

I have a Electron webview, with preload script. Desired webview should look like this:

```
<webview preload="file://./inject.js"></webview>
```

Since I'm building my project using Webpack, inject.js has to be recognized by Webpack, thus included using:
requre('./inject.js')

But, since Electron webviews only accept local files using file:// protocol,

```
preload="require('./inject.js')
```

is not an option.

How can I use `require('./inject.js')` with file:// protocol to include it in a webview preload attribute?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention I'm using electron-vue boilerplate (https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue)

Answer (score 1):

My question was answered by electron-vue maintainer:
https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/239

Comment: Please copy the answer from the linked resource, thanks :)